# Cannot fetch data from Cloud Firestore in SwiftUI Button view

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Why does this not work? There is data in Firestore, but it appears the block doesn't execute:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(
                action: {
                    print("Getting data...")
                    let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("menu")
                    let query = db.order(by: "name", descending: true)
                    query.getDocuments() { snapshot, err in

                        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                          return
                        }
                        print(snapshot)
                        for doc in snapshot.documents {
                            print(doc)
                        }
                    }
                },
                label: { Text("Click Me") }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything's created on stack, so released on quit from action, so cancelled.

Comment: I tried your query, it works fine. Are you sure you're using correct keys? Such as `menu` and `name`?

Comment: Yes double sure one collection called menu, one field called name.

Comment: @asperi can you explain further? The example is lifted from a tutorial that works on Youtube - can't figure out where I'm not right.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Asperi didn't try your query. Do you have `name` key under your `menu` collection? Double check it again, and double check that you have the correct .plist file in your project.

Comment: how is this related to SwiftUI?

Comment: `how is this related to SwiftUI?` - The code is SwiftUI?

Comment: I do @Glenn - the queries are registering in Firebase (from the usage panel) - image of record: https://ibb.co/Rp4bMGQ

Comment: Also have checked plist. When I step through with debugger, the pointer just doesn't enter the block.

Comment: @Glenn thanks in advance for your help on this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Can you post the whole Xcode logs? There should be like `<FIRCollection....xxx12321>`, it means you're getting the data from `print(doc)`.

Comment: ```2020-03-30 10:01:23.055022+0100 SophiesPizza[81513:2975254] 6.0.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2020-03-30 10:01:23.055158+0100 SophiesPizza[81513:2975254] 6.0.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000033] Data Collection flag is not set.
Getting data...```

Comment: Fixed @Glenn thank you. I enabled Firebase/Analytics which seemed to fix it. Very strange. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Way to go, Ben!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add data access logic to a button's action handler. Instead, extract data access logic into a view model (or even a repository), and then add a subscription on the view model's properties like this:

Hypothetical menu item data model:

```swift
struct MenuItem: Identifiable {
  var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  var title: String
}
```

View Model:

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class MenuItemsViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var menuItems = [MenuItem]()

  private var db = Firestore.firestore()

  func fetchData() {
    db.collection("menuitems").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
      guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("No documents")
        return
      }

      self.menuItems = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> MenuItem in
        let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
        let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
        return MenuItem(id: .init(), title: title)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in your view:

```swift
struct MenuItemsListView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = MenuItemsViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(viewModel.menuItems) { menuItem in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(menuItem.title)
            .font(.headline)
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Menu")
      .onAppear() { // (3)
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data mapping can be further simplified by using Firestore's Codable support:

Here's how you need to update the model:

```swift
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct MenuItem: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
  var title: String  
}
```

And here is the updated `fetchData()` method:

```swift
  func fetchData() {
    db.collection("menuitems").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
      guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("No documents")
        return
      }

      self.menuItems = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> MenuItem? in
        return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: MenuItem.self)
      }
    }
  }
```

If this doesn't work, check the log for any error messages (your security rules might be preventing you from reading data, for example).